# How Can I Acheieve This Coloring Effect on Photos

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing

[image: I'd like to find out how this coloring effect was achieved on this photo]

this photo has a really nice effect to it but I'm not sure how I could acheieve the same effect on multiple different photos.

Comment: Erm… define ‘nice’…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This needs serious compression - one shot HDR treatment. If you have a JPG photo with good contrast, but not under- nor overexposing, you can open it in Camera Raw in Photoshop. The result will probably be much better, if you have a real RAW image.

Here is the image in Adobe Camera Raw (part of Photoshop):

[image]

There's maximum fill light(=level lift in shadows without losing local contrast) and vibrancy (=low saturation colors have saturation boost, no boost to already saturated colors)

Adobe Camera Raw has not as much control as other Raw developing programs. That's why I opened the photo in normal Photoshop. There can be done the unreal skintone treatment. Very narrow hue range has got a big lightness and saturation boost and the hue is shifted to more red. The result is heavy pink face powder and bright red lips.

[image]

Your example image has lifted blacks. That appears as reduced contrast. It can be achieved with curves or levels. If you want it, raise the levels at the black end.

[image]

For comparison: A normal treatment to the image would have given the following resutl:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It appears to me that the photo is merely a low contrast photo. Most likely it's *undesired* contrast loss.

But you can see how it *should* look with a simple `Levels` adjustment:

[image]

If you want to mimic the low contrast in another photo, it merely takes a levels adjustment to remove the deep colors in the image:

[image]